# Can an optional field be missing in an extended interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

Given:

```
interface A 
  { a : number
  , b : string  }

interface O // optional additional field
  { a : number
  , opt? : string  };
```

I would expect that `A` cannot be considered an extension of `O`. I understand that the `opt` field is optional, but I kind of interpret it as "a value of O has opt as optional, but an interface extending O must have exactly the same base structure". Am I wrong in this assumption?

Typescript seems to think so, at least given this test (only valid on Typescript 1.8+):

```
function assertSubType<T extends U, U>(x: T, y: U):void { };

assertSubType(<A>null,<O>null); // does not give an error!
```

PS: I've put this same question [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4889#issuecomment-178819795), but it then occured to me that this is perhaps more of missunderstaning of the typescript principles on my part.